# full calendar event Background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, fullcalendar, background-color

I'm working on a project of agenda with Full Calendar linked with a database. First of all, I'm french so sorry for my english.

I use wampserver and PDO extension to connect to my database.
I know how to use php, html but I've very few skills with javascript and jquery.

I've succeeded in programming basic functions and my code is more or less based on this [tutorial](http://www.jqueryajaxphp.com/fullcalendar-crud-with-jquery-and-php/)

Now, I'd like to change background color of the events and save these colors in my database. Ideally, I'd like that every different name of event to be linked to a different background color.
As I have programmed two ways to add/create a new event, this means that:

1 - when I drag and drop on the calendar an external event which, its background color is recorded in the database;

2 - when I select some days directly on the calendar, a pop-up appears to ask me the title of the event: I'd like that if the title I write is known in a list, this event is recorded with the background color associated with the title in the list;

I assume that point 1 is easier to program that point 2 and I'd be happy event if you could just help me to solve point 1.

For the moment, I've created a new column in my database named "backgroundColor" (type varchar, size 255, utf8_general_ci) and I've manually filled these cells with phpmyadmin for the events which were already recorded. I've succeeded in loading and displaying events from the database with correct background color.

However, I don't succeed to program point 1 and 2. I think point 1 is linked to function eventReceive and file add_events and point 2 linked to function select and file add_events.

This is my code:

planning_rbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />

    <link href='assets/css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='assets/css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

    <script src='assets/js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lang-all.js'></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

        var currentLangCode = 'fr';

        var currentMousePos = 
        {
            x: -1,
            y: -1
        };

        jQuery(document).on("mousemove", function (event) 
        {
            currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
            currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
        });

        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() 
        {
            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', 
            {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable(
            {
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });

        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            header: 
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            events: "http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/events_rbs.php",
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            lang: currentLangCode,
            utc: true,
            droppable: true, 

            eventReceive: function(event)
            {
                var title = event.title;
                var start = event.start.format();
                var end = start;
                var backgroundColor = event.backgroundColor;

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/add_events_rbs.php',
                    data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'$backgroundColor='+ backgroundColor,
                    type: "POST"
                });

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);

                console.log(event);
            },

            eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) 
            {
                if (isElemOverDiv()) 
                {
                    var con = confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer cette activité?');
                    if(con == true) 
                    {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/delete_event_rbs.php',
                            data: 'id='+event.id,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },

            select: function(start, end) 
            {
                var title = prompt('Activité:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) 
                {
                    var start = start.format();
                    var end = end.format();

                    eventData = 
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/add_events_rbs.php',
                        data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end ,
                        type: "POST"
                    });

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                }
            },

            eventClick: function(event)
            {
                var title = prompt('Nouveau titre:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });
                if (title)
                {
                    event.title = title;

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/change_title_rbs.php',
                        data: 'title='+title+'&id='+id,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                };
            },

            eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay) 
            {
                var start = event.start.format();
                var end = (event.end == null) ? start : event.end.format();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/update_events_rbs.php',
                    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                    type: "POST"
                });
            },

            eventResize: function(event) 
            {
                start = event.start.format();
                end = event.end.format();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'http://localhost/tests/fullcalendar/update_events_rbs.php',
                    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                    type: "POST"
                });
            }

        });


        function isElemOverDiv() 
        {
            var trashEl = jQuery('#trash');
            var ofs = trashEl.offset();

            var x1 = ofs.left;
            var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
            var y1 = ofs.top;
            var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

            if (currentMousePos.x >= x1 && currentMousePos.x <= x2 && currentMousePos.y >= y1 && currentMousePos.y <= y2) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

</script>
<style>

    body 
    {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    #trash
    {
        width:32px;
        height:32px;
        float:left;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrap 
    {
        width: 1100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #external-events 
    {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #external-events h4 
    {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

    #external-events .fc-event 
    {
        margin: 10px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: green;
    }

    #external-events p 
    {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666;
    }

    #external-events p input 
    {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #calendar 
    {
        float: right;
        width: 900px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="demo-header"></div>

    <div id='wrap'>

        <div id='external-events'>
            <h4>Nouvelle activité</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>IPER</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>Hélitreuillage</div>

            <p>
                <h4>Supprimer activité (faire glisser sur la poubelle)</h4>
                <img src="assets/img/trashcan.png" id="trash" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id='calendar'></div>

        <form action='planning_rbs.php' method='post'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' value="Actualiser la page" />
            </p>
        </form>

        <form action='../page_d_accueil.php' method='post'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' value="Retour à la page d'accueil" />
            </p>
        </form>

        <div style='clear:both'></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

add_events_rbs

```
    <?php

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $start=$_POST['start'];
    $end=$_POST['end'];
    $backgroundColor=$_POST['backgroundColor'];

    // connexion à la base de données
    try 
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pva_test1', 'root', '');
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        exit('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.');
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO planning_rbs (title, start, end, backgroundColor) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :backgroundColor)";
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':backgroundColor'=>$backgroundColor));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
you can use the `eventDrop` and make ajax call inside of it, you can access the `backgroundColor` using

```
eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
  ajax
  console.log(event.backgroundColor)
}
```

2.
 Popover

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) { 
 element.popover({
   title: event.title,
   container: 'body',
   placement: 'auto',
   html: true,
   content: 'your content'
  })
}
```